# Why Ruby array[array.length, count] returns []?

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some kind of unseen Array termination in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857702/is-there-some-kind-of-unseen-array-termination-in-ruby)
>   [Array slicing in Ruby: looking for explanation for illogical behaviour (taken from Rubykoans.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fro)

```
a = %w[a b c]
a[3, 1]    # => []
a[4, 1]    # => nil
```

Could anyone explain why **a[3, 1]** returns **[]**? Why not **nil** instead?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean `array[array.index, array.length]`? Your title is a bit confusing.

Comment: @lemoncider Yes, the title is a bit confusing, but I just want to specify that the **array.index** equals to **array.length**.

Answer (score 3):

Well, looks like [Ruby core documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000218) only mark this as "special case". 
According to The Ruby Programming Language(O'Reilly,2008), the comment on this case is:

```
a[arr_len, len] #=> [], empty array right at the end
a[arr_len + 1, len] #=> nil, nonthing beyond that
```

No further explanation is given. So I think you should just remember the "special case".